# Mockito using what "When ... thenReturn" returns caused NullPointerException

Tags: junit, mockito

I have a third party class called Person, one method is to return a string:

```
public class Person<T> {
   public String getName(Object<T> obj) {
  // some code here
  return "some string"
}
```

And another third party class called SomeClass, one method is to return a Person object:

```
 public class SomeClass {
   public <T> Person<T> createPerson(Object obj) {
    // some code here
    return new Person<T>(....)
   }
 }
```

My class that uses the above two classes to create a person first, then get person's name.  I can't make changes to MyClass because it has been system tested successfully:

```
 public class MyClass {

    public String myMethod() {

        Person<T> person = someClass.createPerson(obj);
        return person.getName(...); 
        // NullPointerException when junit because "person" object is null
    }
 }
```

Now I am working on junit to test MyClass to satisfy the code coverage requirements.  For some reason, it always gave me NullPointer exception when person.getName() is called by junit.

```
public class MyClassTest {

@MockBean
private SomeClass someClass;

@Autowired
private MyClass myClass;

@Test
public void test(){

Person<Student> studentPerson =
     (Person<Student>)Mockito.mock(Person.class);

Mockito.when(someClass.createPerson(ArgumentMatchers.any()))
       .thenReturn(studentPerson);

Mockito.when(studentPerson.getName(ArgumentMatchers.any()))
       .thenReturn("some data");

// call real method
myClass.myMethod(); // failed with NullPointerException
```

I am not sure why studentPerson is not mocked correctly which caused a NullPointerException becacuse it's Null.  Can someone please help?  Thanks.

Comment: We can't help with the fake, partial code you provided, other than by making guesses. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet  The third party classes are very complicated with the use of other generic type classes and collections.  Thus I was trying to show what they return.  The Junit test I posted is the actual code.  My focus was on the Junit test and how to use a mocked return.

Comment: You don't need to post the real code. You need t post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.